# New profile page links to wrong URL for awarded tag badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, tag-badges, 404-not-found

I was [awarded a tag badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/433/url?userid=1591669), and the new profile page congratulated me (in this top-left reputation box on my Activity profile, where the "Next tag badge" gets tracked).

Instead of linking to

```
https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/433/url?userid=1591669
```

it linked to

```
https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/0/url?userid=1591669
```

which is a 404 page.

All other links to this badge on my profile (e.g., in the "Badges" section, the "Badges" tab, the "Badges" box on the Activity profile) seem to be correct.

Answer (score 3):

If a tag badge exists in the DB, the correct URL will be used.

In cases where it doesn't yet (say it is the first one, ever and has not been awarded yet), there will be no link.

With you in the next build.